# How to deactivate the event log in debuging?

Tags: delphi

the event log is very slow on multi thread app and thus completely slow down the app during debugging :

[image]

is their a way to disable it? or at least configure it to ignore Thread Start / Thread Exit entries ?

Comment: Well, then stop creating and destroying threads so frequently.

Comment: @Victoria Indeed, such situations essentially beg for a thread pool.

Comment: @Jerry, sure. Unfortunately, EMBT wasn't yet able to implement native API at least for Windows platform. Things are so simple with it. Though its scaling is great.

Comment: We can only hope EMBT can focus in on the finer details of what we use, instead of providing a wide scope of products. For example, the `Vcl.Printers` unit. Still on extremely old WinAPI calls.

Comment: @Jerry, I'm quite sad how they're focusing on other platforms in favor of the strongest one they've targeted in the past. They innovate, but it takes so long and costs quite much to get just fixes for certain bugs comparing to free, open source development tools (that already offer far much more features). I've grown up on Delphi, but when I'm looking on it right now, I should have better follow C++ path (which I'm trying to return back on).

Comment: @Victoria For sure. I haven't done any C++, but I do understand how much it can make things easier, since many things are based on it. But I myself grew up with Delphi. And the nature of what I do only includes actual code only a portion of the time. So I'm left to my own private projects.

Comment: I say it many times to embt, focus on what you have to make it very good instead of adding and adding new feature that are like most of new features often buggy! And leave the comunity work on tiers tools, good exemple is Indy for exemple that is managed by the community and passionate (like remy lebeu) and even if first version of Indy was really (but really) bad, now it's a quite mature and very good component

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to `Tools` > `Options` then `Debugger Options` > `Event Log` and disable `Thread Messages` on the top right.

[image]